# CoreGraphics For loop only draws some lines

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm intending to draw a compass like graphic with CoreGraphics. I have the following code:

```
// Set origin point
context?.saveGState()
context?.translateBy(x: centreX, y: centreY)

context?.setLineWidth(2.0)
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let components: [CGFloat] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
let color = CGColor(colorSpace: colorSpace, components: components)
context?.setStrokeColor(color!)

for degrees:Double in stride(from: 0, to: 355, by: 5) {

    NSLog("Degrees: \(degrees)")

    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -100))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -80))
    context?.strokePath()

    // Rotate the context
    context?.rotate(by: CGFloat(M_PI * degrees / 180))

}


// Restore the context
context?.restoreGState()
```

My problem is that not all the lines are being drawn. I've verified that it steps through the loop correctly, NSLog shows all required 5 degree increments. but not all those lines are drawn.

[image: Screenshot showing problem]

Any suggestions?

Comment: The rotation is accumulative. I think you want to rotate your context by 5 additional degrees each time: `context?.rotate(by: CGFloat.pi * 5 / 180)`

Comment: Thanks. I should have known that. Thought it was something stupid I was doing.

Comment: You're welcome.  Note my updated comment `CGFloat.pi * 5 / 180` is the new Swift way of referring to pi.

Comment: You might even be able to infer the type and just use `.pi * 5 / 180`.

Comment: So now it tells me I can't use a binary operator * with CGFloat and Int. Is there an inline way to typecast?

Comment: Use `CGFloat(5)` to cast it.

Comment: `NSLog shows all required 5 degree increments. but not all those lines are drawn.` Are you sure they are not overlapped and inside canvas ? Try changing the colour